# SSIS Cannot Acquire Connection

Tags: ssis

I am seeing this error on various `SSIS` packages that are part of an SQL Agent job.  The errors are intermittent. Thus, step 1/package 1 runs fine one day and next day this error occurs.

The full error is the following:

```
Executed as user: RDH\deltekvision. Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility  Version 15.0.4326.1 for 64-bit                                
Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft. All rights reserved.    Started:  1:17:14 AM  Error: 2023-12-27 01:17:15.11                               
Code: 0xC0202009     Source: VP - OpportunityPeriod Connection manager "DestinationConnectionExcel"     Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.                              
An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.  An OLE DB record is available.  S                                
ource: "Microsoft Access Database Engine"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "External table is not in the expected format.".                               
End Error  Error: 2023-12-27 01:17:15.12     Code: 0xC020801C     Source: Data Flow Task 1 Destination - Query [2]     Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.                             
The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "DestinationConnectionExcel" failed with error code 0xC0202009.                             
There may be error messages posted before this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method call failed.  End Error  Error: 2023-12-27 01:17:15.14                             
Code: 0xC0047017     Source: Data Flow Task 1 SSIS.Pipeline     Description: Destination - Query failed validation and returned error code 0xC020801C.                              
End Error  Error: 2023-12-27 01:17:15.15     Code: 0xC004700C     Source: Data Flow Task 1 SSIS.Pipeline     Description: One or more component failed validation.  End Error  Error: 2023-12-27 01:17:15.15                                
Code: 0xC0024107     Source: Data Flow Task 1      Description: There were errors during task validation.                               
End Error  DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).  Started:  1:17:14 AM  Finished: 1:17:15 AM  Elapsed:  0.75 seconds.  The package execution failed.  The step failed
```

.

Essentially, the `SSIS` will create an Excel file and then push data into it.

Set DelayValidation to true.

Comment: You're saying that it runs fine some days, but not fine other days?

Comment: Yes, that is what is happening.  The agent job itself consists of 32 steps, the first step deletes all of the Excel files and then each package will create the Excel file and then push data into the Excel file.  One day the entire job will run, the next day steps 2 and 30 will fail, the next day 10 and 15.  I have not seen it before like this.

Comment: Have you tried enabling retries for each step? Sometimes there's a connection "hiccup" on the network.. for lack of a better word. What is the typical runtime for the entire job, btw?

Comment: I will take a look at  whether there has been retries enabled? Is that at the SQL Agent step level or SSIS level?  

Usually, the entire Agent job takes an hour.

Comment: this is a SQL Agent step configuration.

Comment: I will try that and let you know how it goes. Thanks!